# deadline timer expires, now what?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am looking at the asio example in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/async_tcp_client.cpp

Here's what I am having real trouble to understand:

1. Why does handle_read call back start_read again?
2. What happens when the timer expires? I see no callback routine provided to the timer.

> void start_read()
>     {
>       // Set a deadline for the read operation.
>       deadline_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(30));
>
> ```
> // Start an asynchronous operation to read a newline-delimited message.
> boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, input_buffer_, '\n',
>     boost::bind(&client::handle_read, this, _1));
> ```
>
> }
>
> void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
>     {
>       if (stopped_)
>         return;
>
> ```
> if (!ec)
> {
>   // Extract the newline-delimited message from the buffer.
>   std::string line;
>   std::istream is(&input_buffer_);
>   std::getline(is, line);
>
>   // Empty messages are heartbeats and so ignored.
>   if (!line.empty())
>   {
>     std::cout << "Received: " << line << "\n";
>   }
>
>   start_read();
> }
> else
> {
>   std::cout << "Error on receive: " << ec.message() << "\n";
>
>   stop();
> }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does handle_read call back start_read again?

If it didn't, the client would only ever read the socket once and then never again. So on a successful read, the client wants to attempt a read again. That makes for perpetual reading of the socket.

> What happens when the timer expires? I see no callback routine provided to the timer.

The code is towards the top of the source file:

```
deadline_.async_wait(boost::bind(&client::check_deadline, this));
```

The `check_deadline()` function will close the socket if the deadline has passed.